# Set all fields in form to Null values (including the auto increment) when click button, access

Tags: ms-access

What I want, is that when the user clicks the clear button (as shown in the image below), all fields are set to NULL. This is including the auto increment field, this being volsID, which I want to set to (New), so that when the user inputs data.....it will still increment.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back and think about this functionality. If the form is on an existing, saved, record e.g. with `volsID` 1, do you want that record to:

1. Be deleted?
2. Have all values reset to empty or null values?
3. Reset back to its original values before the user started editing the record in the form?

If (1), then have your click event handler VBA just delete the record and add a new record.

If (2), then have the VBA set all fields to empty values, except for the `volsID` field, which is an AutoNumber field and you can't change that number.

If (3), then just use the form's `Undo` method in the VBA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195175%28v=office.15%29.aspx

If the form is on a new record, before being saved, then you just have to choose between (2) and (3).

Answer (score 0):

If the current record is new, then all you need do is UNDO it (Me.Undo).
If it is not a new record, then you either need to save it or delete it (your choice) and then go to a new record.